# Can I send/receive Java objects to RabbitMQ using Java built-in IO classes instead of Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, io, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I need to send/receive Java POJOs to/from RabbitMQ. There is a ready solution with Spring AMQP, but I've managed to do it with built-in java.io.* (serialize POJO into byte array with ObjectOutputStream + ByteArrayOutputStream and send it to RabbitMQ; on the other side the process is reversed). Is it an equally efficient/safe solution?

**Edit**

I am using com.rabbitmq.client.* library for connections, channels, queues, etc. I was just wondering if I can send objects to RabbitMQ by serializing them into byte arrays using standard classes from java.io.* package, and leave Spring AMQP aside

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Spring AMQP's `SimpleMessageConverter` uses java serialization. Spring's goal is to isolate your code from the lower level amqp-client APIs, reliably close resources, etc, etc. If you use the client directly, your code has to take care of all that.

Comment: You have implemented the AMQP protocol yourself. Good for you now you have to maintain it. What is the reason you would ever want to do that?

Comment: Here is a working tutorial to pass the Java Pojo thought rabbitMQ: https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-messaging-with-rabbitmq/ Its working code on GitHub is here : https://github.com/spring-framework-guru/sfg-blog-posts/tree/master/rabbitmqspringapp